# Day wise Employee Count Based on Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-server-2008

How to calculate the day wise resource count for the below mentioned Scenario:

1. The resource belongs to two different Projects.
2. He makes time sheet entry for each project on same day
3. So when we take the resource count for the day, we need to retrieve
   the count of resource irrespective to the project.

[image: Sample Data]

How can we achieve this in SQL??

Comment: Why post a pitcure of text? Just post the text

Comment: You posted a few different RDMS. I'd remove the erroneous tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `COUNT(DISTINCT  <...>)` on the `Emp.No` column

**SQL Server**

```
select 
   [Date]
   ,[Resource Count] = count(distinct [Emp.No])
from
   YourTable
group by
   [Date]
```